# How to POST to django-tastypie server without authentication

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I know that the default is ReadOnlyAuthorization but as the name states it is read-only and i have the need to POST data. I cant find a setting or example to allow POSTing without authentication. How can i make that possible.

I have done the basic example of tastypie and can GET data so there is not much of code going on.
here is the tutorial : [here](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html)

I have seen some examples using apiKey and username so maybe there is an option to use only apikey?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can set the following in your api.py file:

```
authorization = Authorization()
```

From the docs:

[Tastypie Authorization](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authorization.html#authorization-options)